# Javascript variable scope with event handler

Tags: javascript, html

This is the nth question about JS variable scope but I read through the rest and didn't quite get an answer.

```
var notification = window.webkitNotifications.createNotification(
'image.png',                      // The image.
'New Post: ',// The title.
'New stuff'// The body.
);

var itemLink = 'http://pathtothefile.com';

notification.onclick = function(itemLink) { 
window.focus(); 
window.open(itemLink,'_blank' );
this.cancel(); 
};

notification.show();
```

How do i get itemLink, which is defined in the global scope, to work in the onclick function?

Comment: Remove it from the parameter list.  It's just in there automatically since it's a lower scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the parameter from the function:

```
notification.onclick = function(itemLink) { // overrides itemLink in the global
                                            // object.
```

**Fixed code:**

```
notification.onclick = function() { 
    window.focus(); 
    window.open(itemLink,'_blank' );
    this.cancel(); 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

During name conflicts, local variables take precedence. Remove or rename the argument `itemLink`.

```
notification.onclick = function(something_else) { 
    //global itemLink should be accessible
};
```